# /j_spring_security_check 404 not found only when I deploy it to live server

Tags: maven, spring-security

We have developed an application and deployed it to live server like AWS, nine.ch and etc. Some pages are working fine where login is not required including login page. But when we try to login with the credentials it show an error **/j_spring_security_check 404 NOT Found**. We are developing on windows system and deploying it on Linux based system.

Here are my xml's and related code.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>ModuleWeb</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/pages/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
    <param-value>3</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.allowTextChildren</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
       com.module.config.ModuleContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Spring security configuration  -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- PrettyFaces filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.module.config.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>12097152</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>png</extension>
    <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>pdf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/pdf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.module</groupId>
<artifactId>ModuleWebWeb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>ModuleWeb</name>
<description>spring jpa and primefaces</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springsecurity-version>3.2.1.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>glass-x</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-el</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
        <version>R8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ocpsoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>prettyfaces-jsf2</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.prettytime</groupId>
        <artifactId>prettytime-integration-jsf</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxls-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- FACEBOOK authorization -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.brickred</groupId>
        <artifactId>socialauth-spring</artifactId>
        <version>[2.3,)</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>ModuleWeb</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>WebContent</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txm" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.module.persistence" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.module.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.module.user" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.module.jpa" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.module.jsf" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.module.security" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean id="genericDao" class="com.module.jpa.impl.GenericDAOImpl" scope="singleton" />
<bean id="domainDao" class="com.module.jpa.impl.DomainDAOImpl" scope="singleton" />
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform"
        value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform" />
</bean>

<!-- a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
<bean id="txm" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <!-- (this dependency is defined somewhere else) -->
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="em" />
</bean>
<bean id="em"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="unit_Name" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DBName" />
    <property name="user" value="****" />
    <property name="password" value="****" />

    <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="0" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

**security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Configure Spring Security -->
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll()" />
    <form-login login-page="/pages/login.xhtml"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.xhtml?loginerror=1"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler"
        default-target-url="/pages/index.xhtml" />
    <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/pages/index.xhtml" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="successHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/pages/index.xhtml" />
    <beans:property name="requestCache" ref="requestCache" />
    <beans:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="requestCache"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache">
</beans:bean>

<!-- Define local authentication provider -->
<!-- security -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="bcryptEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.module.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="userService" ref="userDao" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="bcryptEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
</beans:bean>
<global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" />
</beans:beans>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
</application>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>now</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.Date</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

**login.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<h:head>
<f:facet name="first">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</f:facet>
<h:outputScript library="plugins" name="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></h:outputScript>
<h:outputStylesheet library="plugins"
    name="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="pf.css"/> 
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="home.css"/>
</h:head>
<f:view>
<ui:param name="originalURL"
    value="#{request.requestURI}?#{request.queryString}" />
<h:body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-top: 5px">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">#{text.togglenaviagtion}</span>   <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"> </span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{empty userSession.profile}" id="socialButtons">                 
            <div class="content col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-8">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h3 style="text-align: center">Create an account or login to continue</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <form id="loginFormStandalone" method="post" action="  <c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />">
                        <h3 class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 40px;  text-align: center; color: #0089cf;">Login with email</h3>
                        <c:if test="${not empty param.loginerror and param.loginerror eq '1'}">
                            <c:set var="username" value="${sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME}"/>
                        </c:if>
                        <c:if test="${not empty param.loginerror and param.loginerror eq '1'}">
                            <div class="alert alert-warning col-sm-12">
                                #{text.uusernameandpwdrnotvalid}
                            </div>
                        </c:if>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                            <label>#{text.email}</label>
                            <h:inputText id="j_username" value="#{username}" styleClass="form-control"></h:inputText>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                            <label>#{text.password}</label>
                            <h:inputSecret id="j_password" styleClass="form-control"></h:inputSecret>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-5" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <h:commandButton  id="btn" type="submit"
                                    styleClass="btn btn-light-blue btn-lg btn-custom" value="#{text.lgin}"></h:commandButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ui:fragment>
    </div>
    <ui:insert name="footer">
        <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>
    <p:growl id="mainErrorMessages" globalOnly="true"></p:growl>
</h:body>

</f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: A plain spring login url giving 404 that is working on a test server is **not** hibernate, jpa, primefaces related, not at all. Maybe not even maven related.

Comment: Have you checked log files?

Comment: @holmis83 I have checked everything but nothing helpful found there..